# How to check and use the dtype of a numpy array in a condition IF statement using Python 2.7

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dtype

I have a table of data in ArcGIS where I convert certain attribute fields to a numpy array. As the dtype of the array can either be f8 (float64) or i4 (int32), I would like to use an if statement that checks the dtype then does something.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
sorted_data = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(feature_class, (volume_field))
sorted_data.dtype
```

This gives:

```
dtype(['OIL_RECOVERABLE_VOL', '<i4)])
```

What I would like to do is read the dtype using an if statement, similar to this:

```
if sorted_data.dtype == '<i4':
    'do something'
else: # If dtype = <f8
    'do something else'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the compound dtype apart:

```
In [299]: dt=np.dtype([('OIL_RECOVERABLE_VOL', '<i4')])                                                      
In [300]: dt.descr                                                                                           
Out[300]: [('OIL_RECOVERABLE_VOL', '<i4')]
In [301]: dt.descr[0]                                                                                        
Out[301]: ('OIL_RECOVERABLE_VOL', '<i4')
In [302]: dt.descr[0][1]                                                                                     
Out[302]: '<i4'
```

or

```
In [304]: dt['OIL_RECOVERABLE_VOL']                                                                          
Out[304]: dtype('int32')
```